# Javascript funcion para un piano

Tags: javascript, html, web

Estoy haciendo un piano que reproduce los sonidos mediante un `onclick` pero cuando clico 2 veces en la misma nota y la primera vez sigue reproduciéndose la segunda no reproduce el sonido.

El ejemplo es este:

http://94.177.214.187/piano.php

y este es el código:

```
$(document).ready(function()) {

        var sonido = document.getElementById("sonido");
        var sonido2 = document.getElementById("sonido2");
        var sonido3 = document.getElementById("sonido3");  }
```

El sonido lo coge de aqui:

```
 <audio id="sonido">
<source src="midia/220-A%20(mp3cut.net).mp3">
```

`

Y el onclick es este:

```
   <map name="image-maps-2017-03-24-070855" id="pianomaps">
            <area id="negra1" alt="" title="negra1" onclick="sonido16.play()" shape="rect" coords="34,0,62,178" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
            <area id="negra2" alt="" title="negra2" onclick="sonido17.play()" shape="rect" coords="97,0,125,178" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
            <area id="negra3" alt="" title="negra3" onclick="sonido18.play()" shape="rect"  coords="316,0,344,178" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

Comment: ves en consola algun tipo de error?

Comment: `onclick="sonido16.currentTime=0; sonido16.play()"` pero, al margen, ¿por que usar `getElementById` si esas usando JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El script hace exactamente lo que le pedís que haga. Si a un video que estas viendo le das play, el video sigue como si nada. si le das stop o pause y después play, sigue funcionando tal cual. Lo que podrías hacer, no estoy seguro si es lo que querés, es que cada vez que clickees en una tecla, el sonido se reproduzca desde el comienzo, para eso tendrías que hacer:

```
<area id="negra1" alt="" title="negra1" onclick="onKeyClick('sonido16');" shape="rect" coords="34,0,62,178" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

Y el javascript seria algo asi

```
function onKeyClick(objId) {
   var tecla = document.getElementById(objId);
   tecla.pause();
   tecla.currentTime = 0;
   tecla.play();
}
```

Lo que estas haciendo es detener el sonido, rebobinarlo y ejecutarlo cada vez que haces click.